# Put image on top of a page without interfering click events Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a problem, I want to show in an image on top of a Bing `Map` control but I don't want it to interfere with my map control gestures.

The image is a crosshair which is stretch over the page full screen which captures all the click and zoom events making the user unable to use the map.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <m:Map x:Name="LocationMap"/>
    <Image Source="/Assets/Crosshair.png"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `IsHitTestVisible` property was the one I was looking for, by settings this to false on my image control it stops capturing any events.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <m:Map x:Name="LocationMap"/>
    <Image Source="/Assets/Crosshair.png" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```